# Getting column values based on defined order in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a matrix with several columns and I want to get
on special column extracted (as vector), but ordered according to
another column in that matrix.

So far I am doing it with a for-loop approach which I find not
very pretty. I guess that there is a much better way to do such things.

Here a working example:

```
# creating a example matrix with two columns
df <- data.frame(colA=c("A","B","C","D","E"),colB=(1:5))
mat <- as.matrix(df)

# my desired order
my_order <- c("C","D","A","B")

# For loop and collecting results in a vector
out <- NULL
for(i in my_order) out <- c(out,mat[mat[,1]==i,2])

print(out)
```

Any suggestions, examples of a more elegant and computationally faster way?

Comment: What if values are not present in my_order ? And what if values in colA are repeated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match`:

```
df$colB[match(my_order,df$colA)]
```

Since your `colB` is ordered already, just `match(my_order,df$colA)` happens to return the same result, but in general you'll want to index.